# Undefined index "media_type" while adding image to product's media gallery

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, magento-2.1, gallery

Here is the code snippet I use to add an image in a product's media gallery :

```
$sku = 'product-example-sku';
$image_url = 'http://example.com/image.jpg';
$image_ext = pathinfo($image_url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$image_path = '/import/' . $sku . '.' . $image_ext;
file_put_contents('pub/media' . $image_path, file_get_contents($image_url));
if (file_exists('pub/media' . $image_path))
{
    try
    {
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_path, array('image'), true, false);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        echo '[ERROR] Image import failed for product "' . $sku . '": ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

$this->_productRepository->save($product);
```

I am sure that the image is actually downloaded and moved successfully.
But when I try to save the product after adding the image, this exception is thrown by Magento:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: media_type in /var/www/<website>/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php on line 2527
```

I can't find in the Magento core's code how to solve my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi guys, see [bug 6803](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6803) report on github as it pertains to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since **addImageToMediaGallery** is not added to interface `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`, I'd not recommend to use **addImageToMediaGallery** with ProductRepository.

For better practice you can try to use Magento2 Service Layer.
You can save a new image using `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface::create`

If you will go deep to the code, under the hood of the method the attribute "media_gallery" will be set and then `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::save` will be invoked. And inside of this method 
the method `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor::addImage` will be invoked, which basically invoked, when you run **addImageToMediaGallery**

Comment: do you have any concret snippet adding image to product and not using `addImageToMediaGallery()`

Comment: Do you have code snippet for this ? or how i can store using the given answer ? i have read your same answer on lot of blogs but unable to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure **you have to initialize the media gallery first**. I've done that several times and the code I used was always like this:

```
->setMediaGallery(
    [
        'images'=>  [],
        'values'=>  []
    ]
) // Media gallery initialization
->addImageToMediaGallery(
    $image,
    [
        'image',
        'thumbnail',
        'small_image'
    ],
    false,
    false) // Assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the exception is still thrown. Do you save the product before setting the media gallery for the first time, or maybe you can do it after ?

Comment: @ThomasDomingues I always save after

Comment: Thanks. I investigated a little: your solution works when I save the product directly by the product's instance (using `$product->save();`), but when I save it by the products' repository (using `$this->_productRepository->save($product);`), the exception is still thrown.
Is it a better practice to save with the repository instead of saving directly the product instance ? If so, how to solve the issue ?

Comment: @ThomasDomingues you're right it's definitely better practice to use the product repository. I'm not too sure how to fix the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary solution for this [bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6803)

You can use product resource model instead of ProductRepository and it works like a charm. Some code sample here:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResource
)
{
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->productResource = $productResource;
}
public function addImage() {
    $sku = "product-example-sku";
    $image_path = '/import/' . $sku . '.png';
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_path, array('image'), true, false);
    $this->productResource->save($product);
}
```

Comment: Your solution is worked , using resource model, but what if i need to update product ? it shows "URL key for specified store is already exists"

Comment: @ManthanDave In what case did you get this msg? I didn't experience any problems using this code.

Comment: When i save product with - \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResource - Product resource model i am getting this error

Comment: The use of Product Resource Model gives a bunch of different errors , i do not reccomend this as a solution but it does provide intresting information

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution to resolve the issue.

> vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor.php

Please override the file in your theme.

Please search for

```
$mediaGalleryData['images'][] = [
            'file' => $fileName,
            'position' => $position,
            'label' => '',
            'disabled' => (int)$exclude,
               ];
```

and replace with

```
$mediaGalleryData['images'][] = [
            'file' => $fileName,
            'position' => $position,
            'label' => '',
            'disabled' => (int)$exclude,
            'media_type' => 'image',
            'types'      => $mediaAttribute
        ];
```

I have just added `media_type` and types fields here.

I have tested and it's working fine.