# Magento 2: best practice to add/delete product Images programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-upload

I want to upload images to the existing products.
The images are in `import_dir`. And they need to be added to the product that already exists in the catalog.

I could find only 2 ways how to do it.
1. "Bad practice" way - using product model `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::addImageToMediaGallery`

```
1. Copy the images from `import_dir` to `pub/media/tmp`
2. Add the images to the product
3. Save product
```

**Code**

```
    /* copy files from import_dir to pub/media/tmp */

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product */
    /* Init media gallery */
    $mediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
    if (empty($mediaGalleryEntries) === true){
        $product->setMediaGalleryEntries([]);
    }

    /* Add an image to the product's gallery */
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery(
        $filePathFromTmpDir,
        [
          "image",
          "small_image",
          "thumbnail",
          "swatch_image" 
        ],
        $moveImage,
        $disableImage
    );

    /* Save */
    $this->_productRepository->save($product);
```

2. "Good practice" way - **using API** `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface::create`

```
1. Create image content object via **\Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterfaceFactory**
2. Create image object via **\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterfaceFactory**
3. Create an image via API
```

**Code**

```
    $imageContent = $this->_imageContentInterfaceFactory->create()
        ->setBase64EncodedData(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePathImportDir)))
        ->setType($this->_mime->getMimeType($filePathImportDir))
        ->setName($file_name);

    $newImage = $this->_productAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterfaceFactory->create()
        ->setMediaType(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media\ImageEntryConverter::MEDIA_TYPE_CODE)
        ->setFile($filePathImportDir)
        ->setDisabled($disableImage)
        ->setContent($imageContent)
        ->setLabel('label');

    $this->_productAttributeMediaGalleryManagement->create($product->getSku(), $newImage);
```

**Concerns:**

- In **1** I'm getting an error, which is [known issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134095/undefined-index-media-type-while-adding-image-to-products-media-gallery)

  > Undefined index: media_type
- In **2** is way too complicated and it should be the easier way

**Questions:**

- Is there "best practice" way to manage(add, remove, replace) product's images?
- Maybe there is a way with **\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product**

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using your second way, more or less like this:

```
<?php


namespace [vendor]\[moduleName]\Model\Adminhtml\Product\MediaGallery;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\EntryFactory;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\GalleryManagement;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\ImageContentFactory;

{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\EntryFactory
 */
private $mediaGalleryEntryFactory;


/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\GalleryManagement
 */
private $mediaGalleryManagement;


/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\ImageContentFactory
 */
private $imageContentFactory;


/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\EntryFactory $mediaGalleryEntryFactory
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\GalleryManagement $mediaGalleryManagement
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ImageContentFactory $imageContentFactory
 */
public function __construct
(
    EntryFactory $mediaGalleryEntryFactory,
    GalleryManagement $mediaGalleryManagement,
    ImageContentFactory $imageContentFactory
)
{
    $this->mediaGalleryEntryFactory = $mediaGalleryEntryFactory;
    $this->mediaGalleryManagement = $mediaGalleryManagement;
    $this->imageContentFactory = $imageContentFactory;
}


/**
 * @param string $filePath
 * @param string $sku
 */
public function processMediaGalleryEntry($filePath, $sku)
{
    $entry = $this->mediaGalleryEntryFactory->create();

    $entry->setFile($filePath);
    $entry->setMediaType('image');
    $entry->setDisabled(false);
    $entry->setTypes(['thumbnail', 'image', 'small_image']);

    $imageContent = $this->imageContentFactory->create();
    $imageContent
        ->setType(mime_content_type($filePath))
        ->setName('test')
        ->setBase64EncodedData(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath)));

    $entry->setContent($imageContent);

    $this->mediaGalleryManagement->create($sku, $entry);
}

}
```

`$filePath` should be an absolute path - maybe you can use constans `BP`.

Comment: it's sad that there is no more good ways to solve it, cuz as @JakubIlczuk said - it's highly limited. About this `$entry->setMediaType('image');` line i'm not quite sure, cuz as far as i remember it caused me an error something like that it's need a type "png" or "jpg"(so in the end it should be "image/png"). But again, i'm not sure

Comment: In magento 2.1.1 it is no causing such an error.

Comment: Neither method addresses remove or replace. Just an observation.

Answer (score 0):

after looking at the same things as You apparently I'm at exactly the same place, and can't find any better way then this 2. And this 2 are highly limited.
In functional tests they are using simple product->save() thing which causes other problems (for me personally, url_key already exists error).
Seems like only 2nd method can be used, however complicated and confusing it seems. But I wonder if in 2nd method you've found a way to set the uploaded images as thumbnail or small image?