# Add image to product programatically not using addImageToMediaGallery

Tags: magento2, product-images, programmatically, repository

Method `addImageToMediaGallery()` seems to me buggy, [when using `productRepository` to save product](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5249), what encourage us to use deprecate method `save()` directly from product model (what causes other bugs), when trying to add product programatically. What is the correct way to add image, what classes should I use in order to perform it using repository. I have added question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134095/undefined-index-media-type-while-adding-image-to-products-media-gallery) in comments (accepted answer seems to provide some general clues), but I think this subject deserves separte question, as stack and internet tutorials are full of deprecate code. Some real example of code would be extremely useful.

**EDIT**

I have found an answer - it can be done using other object - example [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151656/magento-2-best-practice-to-add-delete-product-images-programmatically/152770#152770)

Comment: you need to share your code here, what you have try.

Comment: I want to create product programatically and add an image to it, not using `addImageToMediaGallery()`

Comment: I am asking to share your code.

Comment: I know what you asking, but it doesn't matter - I ask just for GENERAL way of adding image without using mentioned method. So it should work with any code. Product data can be example

Comment: Then you need to create another attribute and upload image into that and then show that attribute value every where.