# Notice: Undefined index: media_type in vendor/magento/module-product-video/Model/Plugin/Catalog/Product/Gallery/ReadHandler.php on line 60

Tags: magento2

Getting this error on manage products page of Magento 2 version 2.2.6 after uploading an image:

> Notice: Undefined index: media_type in
>   vendor/magento/module-product-video/Model/Plugin/Catalog/Product/Gallery/ReadHandler.php
>   on line 60

That is in developer mode.
In Production mode the site give a general 503 error.

Another error in php 7.0 on `content > design configuration > edit` is a spinning wheel and in chrome console this:

> dynamic-rows.js:1035 Uncaught TypeError:
>   this.getChildItems(...).forEach is not a function
>
> file-uploader.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: value.map is not a function

Comment: maybe you can find your answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134095/undefined-index-media-type-while-adding-image-to-products-media-gallery

Comment: I saw that, but that question is more about saving images programatically, this is just using the admin UI

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find the root cause of this but if you change the php from 7.0 to 7.1 both errors go away